# Stop nolio deployment on command line script fail

Tags: devops, continuous-deployment, psake, nolio

I've tried to search for this but i couldn't fine anything. I have a Nolio flow that has a command line action to deploy a solution with psake. The command line is run like this:

```
psake.cmd .\deploy.ps1 -parameters @{env='Environment'} if ($psake.build_success -eq $false) { exit 1 } else { exit 0 }
```

But if the script deploy.ps1 fails the nolio deployments hangs and need to be stopped manually.

Is there a way to make the deployment stop automatically when the script fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this. Nolio offers an action called "ROC - Fail Deployment Step". I achieved what i wanted by  deselecting the pause on failure and adding this action after the script execution and setting the operation on link to "On failed"